# Why are the two results of this limit inconsistent?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

It is a well know result that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$ so we should have the result that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^2\sin \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=1$$ yet when I plug the limit into an online calculator it uses the squeeze theorem and shows that $$-x^2 \leq x^2\sin \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \leq x^2 $$ because of the values $\sin$ can take. This leads us to the result that the limit is zero because of the limits of $x^2,-x^2$ as $x$ tends to zero.

Why is the middle line wrong though? I've been sat for a while thinking about it but I can't see why I'm guessing there is something obvious I'm not spotting.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^2\sin \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=1$?

Comment: $x \to 0$ in the first limit corresponds to $x \to \infty$ in the second.

Comment: Ah okay I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: Robert please post yours as an answer and I will approve.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That should really be an answer, not a comment...

Answer (score 3):

As requested, I'm making my comment into an answer:

$x \to 0$ in the first limit corresponds to $x \to \infty$ in the second.

I should make that a bit more precise.
It is better to use a different name for the variable in the other limit.
With $t = 1/\sqrt{|x|}$ 
$$\eqalign{\lim_{x \to 0+} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} &= \lim_{t \to \infty} t^2 \sin(1/t^2)\cr
\lim_{x \to 0-} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} &= \lim_{t \to \infty} -t^2 \sin(-1/t^2) = \lim_{t \to \infty} t^2 \sin(1/t^2) \cr}$$

Answer (score 1):

Robert has the correct answer in the comments: $x\to 0$ in the first limit corresponds to $x\to \infty$ in the second limit, so the analogy is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^2\sin \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=0$$
because $\left|\sin \left( \frac{1}{x^2} \right) \right|\leq 1$ and
$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} x^2=0$

Regarding $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$
For one that knows the L'Hospital Rule it is simple
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(x)}{1}=1$$

Without the L'Hospital Rule go to [Link](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQtwIwAGoVChMIwI-f36rCyAIV5ehyCh3USAFD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.khanacademy.org%2Fmath%2Fdifferential-calculus%2Flimits_topic%2Fsqueeze_theorem%2Fv%2Fproof-lim-sin-x-x&usg=AFQjCNE9X0U0CHcDMh0dNtBzEx3vwG8pmQ&sig2=4mVeX97e2fJoQUSy91DWJg&bvm=bv.105039540,d.bGQ) it user some geometry basics and squeeze theorem, shouldn't not that difficult to understand.
Another option is [Another Link](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CEUQFjAHahUKEwjAj5_fqsLIAhXl6HIKHdRIAUM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.tamu.edu%2F~mpilant%2Fmath646%2FHW%2Fhw4%2Fsolutions.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFif8qtl_9b-Am5dRDZl8dFBBggNw&sig2=qEvCtYCpJjCH78U_DeFZGA&cad=rja).

Comment: This answer does not really address OP's main source of confusion, though...

Comment: @Michael Medvinsky. It is not appropriate to use L'Hospital's Rule for this limit. Your link is the right way

Comment: @imranfat  this why the link exists

Comment: @5xum didn't get you